# How to implement the Three.js scene example in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js

How to implement the Three.js getting started example for a scene [1] in Vue.js 3 using JavaScript (!= TypeScript)?

[1] https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene

main.js

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

animate();
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . If you have a specific problem regarding your implementation, consider asking about it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer for fellow seekers. Luckily there are places in the internet where the people are less snobbish about perfectly valid questions [1].

*App.vue*

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import * as THREE from 'three';

const target = ref();

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(500, 500);

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
  cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

onMounted(() => {
  target.value.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  animate();
});
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="target"></div>
</template>
```

[1] https://github.com/vuejs/core/discussions/9057